# Unable to save file in python

Tags: python, file

Trying to save files in python:

```
g = open('~/ccna_pages/'+filename, 'w')
g.write(page)
g.close()
```

Get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dl-pages.py", line 50, in
>   
>       g = open('~/ccna_pages/'+filename, 'w') IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/ccna_pages/1.0.1.1.html'

However, the directory does exist at that location.

This syntax seems to be the what the python docs recommend..  http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node46.html

What am I missing? Thanks..

Comment: As a debugging method, try just writing a file without the filepath and just a name to make sure that isn't the problem

Comment: You probably don't want to read the Python 1.5 docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't expand `~` for you, you need to do it by hand.

Example:

```
>>> with open('~/test', 'w') as f:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/test'
>>> with open('/home/mihai/test', 'w') as f:
...     pass
...
```

Comment: get +1 from me. -1 is probably from someone considering question too noob to be answered, it happens

Answer (score 2):

The `os.path` module is full of goodies, including [`expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
import os

filename = 'whatever.txt'
dir = '~/ccna_pages/'

if dir.startswith('~'):
    dir = os.path.expanduser(dir)

path = os.path.join(dir, filename)
print(path)  # /home/some1/ccna_pages/whatever.txt
```